# Store number of rows in SQL query as a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write some PHP that will run an SQL query and then count the number of rows that query returned and store it so i can use it in an if statement. Currently i am outputting the number onto the screen for debug reasons and it always outputs as 0 whereas when i run the query directly in the database it returns over 600 rows. Why is this?

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `bets` WHERE `user` = 76561198223084096');
$row_cnt = $result->mysql_num_rows;
printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$row_cnt);
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: use `count(*)` instead of `*`?

Comment: actually: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: change `$row_cnt = $result->mysql_num_rows;` to `$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);`

Comment: Show the code of initialising `$db`.

Comment: I tried "change $row_cnt = $result->mysql_num_rows; to $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);" but i still get 0 rows in the output

Answer (score 1):

> ... it always outputs as 0 whereas when i run the query directly in the database it returns over 600 rows.

The problem is because of this statement,

```
$row_cnt = $result->mysql_num_rows;
```

It should be,

```
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
```

Here's the reference:

- [mysqli_result::$num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: I still get 0 as an output from this

Comment: @Tyler Run this query `SELECT * FROM \`bets\` WHERE \`user\` = 76561198223084096;` in your MySQL console and see if it returns any row or not.

Comment: Just ran it and: "Showing rows 0 - 99 (646 total, Query took 0.0008 seconds.)"

Comment: @Tyler *hmm, strange*.  Try to debug this issue using [`mysqli::$error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). Also check whether you're properly connected to database or not i.e check the status of `$db` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution:

```
$counter = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM `bets` WHERE `user` = '76561198223084096'") ;
$num = mysql_fetch_array($counter);
$row_cnt= $num["cnt"];
printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$row_cnt);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same db with the code, otherwise you should have got the same result with your code too.

Comment: I use $db 100s of times in the code and it works fine for all the rest, just not at this point

Comment: Check my edit, use a single quote before the no. in the query.

Comment: Try to run my query in your db and check what it will return.

Comment: Just ran it and: "Showing rows 0 - 99 (646 total, Query took 0.0008 seconds.)"

Comment: This is something strange, because this is how we calculate number of rows.. I think you should have a cup of coffee and then debug your code line by line very calmly to find the exact issue. I am sure you will find it... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $db->query("select count(*) as c from `bets` WHERE `user` = '76561198223084096'");
$count = $result->fetch_object()->c;

echo "Result set has {$count} rows ";
```

Comment: can you check it once

Comment: I just tried the edited version and still got the error

Comment: $db instead of $mysqli